# How do I generate an Allure report in NUnit 3?

Tags: nunit, allure

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't found an answer anywhere else.

I have set up Allure as described in the documentation for NUnit 3. After I run my tests through the VS Test Runner I can see the result.json and attachment.txt files in my allure-results directory, but I don't understand how this translates into the actual Allure report, shown at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unickq/allure-nunit/master/AllureScreen.png.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on generating Allure reports for tests in C# recently and I can share what I discovered.

Indeed there is this NUnit Allure adapter which you mentioned: [NUnit Allure](https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit) Now it is archived and the maintained library is [Allure.NUnit](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/tree/main/Allure.NUnit)

I had errors when trying to install [Allure.NUnit](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/tree/main/Allure.NUnit) -> see [Issue created](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/issues/341) hopefully this will be fixed / resolved

=========================

I [documented detailed steps for a working Allure + NUnit Allure adapter](https://github.com/ralupopa/EXAMPLES-CSharp-Standalone-AltTrashCat/blob/master/setup_allure.md)